# ConfigureAwait: On which thread is the exception handled?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

When you `await` a `Task`, the continuation by default runs on the same thread. The only time you ever actually need this is if you're on the UI thread, and the continuation needs to run on the UI thread as well.

You can control this by using `ConfigureAwait`, e.g.:

```
await SomeMethodAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

...which can be useful to offload work from the UI thread that doesn't need to run there. (But see Stephen Cleary's comment below.)

Now consider this bit of code:

```
try
{
    await ThrowingMethodAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Which thread am I on now?
}
```

And how about this?

```
try
{
    await NonThrowingMethodAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    // At this point we *may* be on a different thread

    await ThrowingMethodAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Which thread am I on now?
}
```

Comment: The first version of async/await did support exceptions this way, what is new is the fact that you can now call `await` in a `catch` block which you could not before. Calling `await` in a `try` block was perfectly fine in C# 5

Comment: @Scott: Thanks for the correction!

Comment: ...updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @PetterHesselberg: `When you await a Task, the continuation by default runs on the same thread.` No, this is not correct. I have an [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) that explains how async methods are resumed. Also, `which can be useful to offload work from the UI thread that doesn't need to run there` is dubious - it's only true if the async operation actually completes asynchronously; it will *not* leave the UI thread if it completes synchronously (e.g., downloading a cached resource). The proper way to offload work is `Task.Run`.

Comment: @Stephen: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The exception will be on whatever thread the continuation would have happened on had there been no exception.

```
try
{
    await ThrowingMethodAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Which thread am I on now?
    //A: Likely a Thread pool thread unless ThrowingMethodAsync threw 
    //   synchronously (without a await happening first) then it would be on the same
    //   thread that the function was called on.
}

try
{
    await NonThrowingMethodAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    // At this point we *may* be on a different thread

    await ThrowingMethodAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Which thread am I on now?
    //A: Likely a Thread pool thread unless ThrowingMethodAsync threw 
    //   synchronously (without a await happening first) then it would be on the same
    //   thread that the function was called on.
}
```

For some more clarity:

```
private async Task ThrowingMethodAsync()
{
    throw new Exception(); //This would cause the exception to be thrown and observed on 
                           // the calling thread even if ConfigureAwait(false) was used.
                           // on the calling method.
}

private async Task ThrowingMethodAsync2()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    throw new Exception(); //This would cause the exception to be thrown on the SynchronizationContext
                           // thread (UI) but observed on the thread determined by ConfigureAwait
                           // being true or false in the calling method.
}

private async Task ThrowingMethodAsync3()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);
    throw new Exception(); //This would cause the exception to be thrown on the threadpool
                           // thread but observed on the thread determined by ConfigureAwait
                           // being true or false in the calling method.
}
```

Comment: Excuse me by what do you mean with your answer.
It's confusing for me, will the exception be handled or not?
The Exception will be on whatever thread the conuation is planed.
This says to me, ok continuation is planed on ThreadPoolThread or OriginThread,
But what exact do you me with on had there been no exception.
Do you mean that it will look for the try-catch as if there would have never been an exception?

Comment: So it sounds like, yes and no answer for me