# ConfigureAwait(false) and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ContextTransaction

Tags: async-await, azureservicebus, configureawait

Is the following C# code guaranteed to have always sent a message if it is recorded as having been sent in the database, or does the `ConfigureAwait(false)` mean it is possible to have recorded something as sent in the Db even if it was not sent, say if network failed at just the right moment.

This [does an exception propagate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63380165/does-an-exception-propagate-using-configureawaitfalse-with-async-task-and-awai) seems to indicate exceptions might not always propagate due to the `ConfigureAwait(false)`

```
public async Send(string message){
   await using var transaction = await _dbContext.BeginTransactionAsync(cancellationToken);
   _dbContext.SentEvents.Add(message);
   await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
   await _publisher.PublishAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(false);
   await transaction.CommitAsync();
}
```

The reason I ask it it seems, Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusSender 7.10.0.0 uses ConfigureAwait(false) internally. Assume for the sake of the question that _dbContext is microsoft entity framework and the transaction an `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IDbContextTransaction`

Or is there a better way of only persisting a record of a message as having been sent in the DB only if it sent by ServiceBusSender? So we can guarantee at least once delivery.

Comment: I think actually maybe my problems are due to this.. https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23850   as the method exits the DB rolls back but maybe not the context so the sent events gets updated by a later call to Send ... I'm not sure

Comment: You won't see coordination between your database success and your Service Bus operation.  It does not participate in transactions with other components - only with other Service Bus operations.

Comment: `ConfigureAwait(false)` has no effect on exception propagation. The exception will propagate with or without it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the following C# code guaranteed to have always sent a message if it is recorded as having been sent in the database

Yes.

> This does an exception propagate? seems to indicate exceptions might not always propagate due to the ConfigureAwait(false)

The [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63380165/does-an-exception-propagate-using-configureawaitfalse-with-async-task-and-awai) never provided a reproducible test case. No one except the op ever observed that behavior.

`ConfigureAwait(false)` has no effect on exception propagation. The exception will propagate (preventing the transaction from completing) with or without `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

> Or is there a better way of only persisting a record of a message as having been sent in the DB only if it sent by ServiceBusSender? So we can guarantee at least once delivery.

It's a bit unusual to keep the message in the db after it's sent; the more common pattern is to delete the message in the db after it's sent. That said, this code should work fine. The Googleable term is "outbox pattern".